# Svelte Auto Subscription in OnMount

Tags: typescript, svelte, onmount

I have a simple Svelte project that uses a store to hold shared data across components.
Part of this project also references HTML elements (for example a username input field).

Reading the documentation [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this) and [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions), I understood that I need to:

- Bind an HTML element in the onMount method
- I can use auto subscription ($) instead of manual subscription and not have to deal with unsubscribing through the **onDestroy** method

At first, I used manual subscription and everything worked well. When I moved to automatic subscription, it did not work and the values didn't get updated.

Below is a minimal example with automatic subscription:

**Spinner.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { shouldShowSpinner } from './AppStore';
    import { onMount} from 'svelte';

    let spinnerDiv
  

    onMount(() => {
        spinnerDiv.style.display = $shouldShowSpinner ? "inline-block" : "none"
      })

   
</script>

<main>
   <div id="spinner" bind:this={spinnerDiv}>
   </div>
</main>
```

**UserInput.svelte:**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { shouldShowSpinner } from './AppStore';

    let username = "";

    function foo() {
        if (username.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        $shouldShowSpinner = true
        ...
    }

   
</script>

<main>
    <div id="userInput">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username?" bind:value={username}/> 
        <button id="search" on:click={foo}>Search</button>
     </div>
</main>
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should generally *not* need to access elements. If you use idiomatic Svelte, the problem takes care of itself here.

`onMount` only runs once. Auto-subscription does not mean that the code will re-run, it just means that the store content will be accessed without leaking a subscription. When/how code runs still follows reactivity rules.

To fix the code, you would need a reactive statement like this:

```js
$: if (spinnerDiv) spinnerDiv.style.display = ...
```

But that is not how to do this. Instead, just use `{#if}`, toggle a class or change the style in the template:

```html
{#if $shouldShowSpinner}
   <div>...
{/if}
```

```html
<div class="spinner" class:show={$shouldShowSpinner}>...
<style>
  .spinner { display: none; }
  .spinner.show { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

```html
<div style:display={$shouldShowSpinner ? "inline-block" : "none"}>...
```

No need to use `bind:this` at all.

Comment: Thanks @H.B.. I know that onMount only runs once and that automatic subscription does not mean that the code will rerun. But per the documentation it is said to bind HTML elements there so I did not understand what should be the best approach.